# Android swipeable text view

Tags: android, swipe

I am trying to create a app where you would get a list of strings and you are able to swipe through them. What I had in mind is to have a text view and every time you swipe the text is changed to the next element in the list.

But I am under the impression that this might not be the best way to do things. Is there any other way I could do this ?

Comment: You can use view pager

Comment: if you don't need any special animation affect like paging a book i think your idea would be enough and it will work fine